# Google Places API autocomplete specific city

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I have some questions about google places api for android.

This is the request that is being called:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?sensor=false&key=API_KEY&components=country:hr&language=hr&input=lad

The issue is that I want only addresses within specific city. Is that possible?

Here is the quote from 
[Google Places API autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete)
that suggests that it should work.

> Blockquote the (regions) type collection instructs the Place service to return any result matching the following types:

- locality
- sublocality
- postal_code
- country
- administrative_area1
- administrative_area2

> Blockquote the (cities) type collection instructs the Place service to return results that match either locality or administrative_area3.

So I would like to specify citry or a postal code in order to filter only addreses from that city.

--EDIT--

This approach doesn't work either.

> maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?sensor=false&key=API_KEY&types=geocode&location=45.811093,15.974121&radius=12000&components=country:hr&language=hr&input=lad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

I've added CIty name in input string

city_name+street like Zagreb+fal in order to get all the streets from Zagreb with fal* in their name.

It seems to be working oke.

Comment: How did you do that? where you added the city name?

Comment: At the end, &input={CITY_NAME}+user_input

Comment: Please, post complete example.